# WaitForSingleObject doesn't timeout

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

The following simple code doesn't operate as I expected. It creates a thread (suspended), starts it, waits for it to run for 1 millisecond and loops waiting until the thread dies or fails.

I expected the output to be something along the lines of:

> Start
>   Callback running
>   Callback running
>   Callback running
>   WaitForSingleObject looping
>   Callback running
>   Callback running
>   WaitForSingleObject looping
>   Callback running
>   Callback running
>   WaitForSingleObject looping
>   Callback running
>   Callback running
>   ... repeating for 10000 times
>   End
>   Thread end

But the output is:

> Start
>   Callback running
>   Callback running
>   Callback running
>   Callback running
>   Callback running
>   ... repeating for 10000 times
>   Callback running
>   End
>   WaitForSingleObject looping
>   Thread end

I thought that the wait in `WaitForSingleObject` would timeout at some point and interrupt the thread at some point? But the thread seems to be blocking and not asynchronous?

```
DWORD WINAPI callback(LPVOID param)
{
    printf("Start\n");

    for (int i=10000; i>0; i--)
        printf("Callback running\n");

    printf("End\n");
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, callback, 0, CREATE_SUSPENDED, 0);

    if (!hThread) {
        printf("Failed to create thread\n");
        return 0;
    }

    ResumeThread(hThread);
    while (WaitForSingleObject(hThread, 1) == WAIT_TIMEOUT) {
        printf("WaitForSingleObject looping\n");
    }

    CloseHandle(hThread);
    printf("Thread end\n");

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your thread is not performing any yielding operations that give up CPU time until the thread terminates. Try having the thread loop call `Sleep()` periodically and you will see the OS able to switch back to the main thread periodically so it can react to the timeout.

Comment: You could also increase the number of rotations inside the thread. Computers are fast and just 10k outputs might take less than the typical thread's timeslice. Search the web what that timeslice is, it varies in the MS Windows family of OSs. Further, `WaitForSingleObject()`, `Sleep()` and other functions like those will typically sleep for *at* *least* the given time! There's no guarantee that it will sleep anywhere near 1ms in your case. That's due to the timeslice of the other thread but also that of all other threads of other processes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dwMilliseconds` parameter in `WaitForSingleObject` cannot be relied upon for accurate timing. The only contract is that after that much time has elapsed, the thread will *eventually* wake up and return the `TIMEOUT` value. The thread may not wake up until its next scheduled quanta, which can be as high as 60 milliseconds (or even higher on Windows Server). This is more than enough time for the second thread to complete. Try increasing the iteration count such that the worker thread takes at least one second to run - that should be plenty of time for the primary thread to be scheduled and run at least one more iteration of the `TIMEOUT` loop.